# Random data loss (NSUserDefaults) when popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

From time to time, my app loses all data when using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case kLANG_HEBREW:
            // Hebrew is the default
            self.arrayOfLanguages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"he", @"en", nil];
            break;
        case kLANG_ENGLISH:
            self.arrayOfLanShorts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"he", nil];
            break;
        case kLANG_RUSSIAN:
            self.arrayOfLanShorts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ru", @"en", nil];
            break;
        case kLANG_ARABIC:
            self.arrayOfLanShorts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", @"en", nil];
            break;
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.arrayOfLanShorts forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"come_from_change_lang"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];    
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thats very strange since I don't clear data in my app.

Comment: are you sure it is not entering switch condition 'kLANG_HEBREW', because there you have used self.arrayOfLanguages, in that case, self.arrayOfLanShorts, might be blank and after switch statement, it always saves self.arrayOfLanShorts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your switch statement isn't always setting `self.arrayOfLanShorts` and it is then nil. Then when you set that in our user defaults it nils out the stored value and it would appear you lost your data. I would put a check of an if statement that your array is not nil before adding it to the defaults and if it is trace down how it didn't hit your switch statement.